# Play 2.x Scala Controller clarification needed

Tags: scala, playframework, controller, playframework-2.0

I have been studying and playing with Scala and at the same time I have been trying to learn Play! and especially Scala version play.

I understand the apply-methods of an object and even passing code block to Trait or Class. But in all examples Action-code block example is something like :

```
def index = Action {
Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

So in here we are using Action-companion object helper and we are passing code block to this companion objects apply-function ?

But what I don't understand is where to "request" is populated from ? This is something I have encountered with Scala, some "mysterious" magic just happens but I need to understand it. :)

So if someone could explain this to Scala and Play! newbie your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not so magical (in this instance at least). Controllers receive a request and produce a response. In Play you can write this if you don't need to access or use any of the request information:

```
def index = Action {
   Ok("hello, world")  // Not using the request!
}
```

But the code as you've written it (as of now) won't actually compile because, as you say, the request isn't given. Instead you need to do this:

```
def index = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

i.e. the request is a parameter to a function that returns a `Result` (the `Ok`).

And yes, you're right, it's equivalent to writing:

```
def index = Action.apply({ request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
})
```

or even more explicitly:

```
def myAction[T]: (Request[T] => Result) = request => Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")

def index = Action.apply(myAction)
```

*The `index` is **not** a function that returns a response directly. It is a function the framework calls to obtain a handler for a request (the `Action`). That handler can then be invoked with the incoming request to produce a response.*

---

There are other variations. By default, the content of the request (i.e. the body) is handled as a general purpose `AnyContent`. If you want to explicitly parse the body in some particular way, for instance as JSON, you can pass a `BodyParser` as the first (curried) argument:

```
def index = Action(myBodyParser) { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

---

Note: it's common to make the request an implicit parameter so it will, for example, get automatically passed to templates:

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.mypage())
}
```

For some template code like:

```
@()(implicit request: RequestHeader)

<h1>I was called at @request.path</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made a mistake in the code, what I meant was like your example. But what I was wondering is were does the request come to code block ? If I have say def index() which return Result, and that Result is the result of the Action block. But the index() method never receives the request (as a parameter at least). So is the request populated somewhere in the object ? I know it's stupid question but with Java-background it is strange that I have parameter but it is not defined where it comes from ? I don't see the object receiving the value anywhere ?

Comment: I have attempted to answer your question but it'll definitely be worth doing some additional reading about FP and Scala (syntax and philosphy). TL;DR, the `index` is a function that returns another function. There's no magic there.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My question id more regarding Scala. I know Action is a trait which has companion object to create Actions. But you pass a code block to the companion object which creates Result object. But where does the "request" come from if I have not defined it anywhere in the controller ? Does come from superclass/trait ?

Comment: I know this is more regarding the syntax. But I am hard trying to wrap my head around "variables/objects" I have not defined anywhere. I know to basic syntax and functional features of Scala but when I see code I which is more than simple examples, I have hard time trying to understand the syntax.

Comment: Also I am little confused am I passing a code block here ? Not a function literal like with collections ? And sorry for repeating my self, but if I have code block I can reference objects that are in scope, so where the "request" reference come from ? From Action companion object or from Controller superclass/trait ? I cant remember which one it was. :) I was tried to lookup it from Java version of play and there Response was static-method so I quess it is populated in Controller ? Or I am just over my understanding and you cannot teach old dog new tricks ;)

Comment: Ahh, trying to understand new syntax and framework can be hard and dangerous... ;) The request is populated by the framework in the Controller superclass.